# Help in using OpenCV - Errors of type: identifier not found

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Am a beginner to OpenCV and have gone so far as to work out the hello world samples, inverting, color conversion(RGB->greyscale ) etc programs working.
However i am stuck at the Programs that use cvCanny, cvPyr and other such feature detectors.Would really be thankful if the tiny prblem was sorted out .

I get the Error:    error C3861: 'cvPyrDown': identifier not found
                   error C3861: 'cvCanny': identifier not found

I've included the imgproc and features2d headers yet the problem persists.
What am I missing out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your "Additional input directories" property set correctly?

Mine, configured by cmake, looks like this:

```
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/release
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/include/opencv
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/imgproc/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/features2d/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/gpu/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/calib3d/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/objdetect/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/video/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/ml/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/legacy/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/contrib/include
C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/flann/include
```

Btw. CMake is a nice tool if you are dealing with libraries that contains many include files,  line OpenCV.

You can also check two other things:

1. After compiling OpenCV2.2 from sources, did you built "INSTALL" project in the OpenCV VS solution?
2. If you are using c++ headers, you might prefer c++ version of those functions,
   in the cv namespace:

   cv::Canny(...)

Comment: I compiled using  CMake itself.Built the Install project under the OpenCV sln. was built successfully. The additional input directories in VS 2010- I have these directories in the list of VC++ Additional include directories yet i get the same Erros. I find no Additional Include Directories category. Could you please explain how to make use of C++ versions of the functions? cos using cv::Canny(args) gives me the error that Canny is not a member of cv. Thanks for such a detailed reply :)

Comment: to use c++ version, include #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: that did it :) i dont believe i missed that out :O . Thanks for the patient replies.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a link error rather than any problems with include. Are you sure you are linking with cv.lib?

Comment: I dont see a cv.lib anyhwere in the opencv directory hierarchy.Am using the openCv 2.2 ver. in the Linker section i have the following in the additional dependencies list, anything i need to add? opencv_core220d.lib,opencv_highgui220d.lib ,opencv_ml220d.lib,opencv_imgproc220d.lib,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the $(OPENCV_ROOT)/lib directory to the linker path so it knows where to search for the files.

From the description, I assume you're using Visual Studio? If so, you have two options for doing so.

1. Add it to this project under Project ->  Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories.
2. Add it for all projects: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Library files. And then add folders there.